# how to connect an angular app on public ip to a node app on local server?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ip, httpservice

I have an angular 4 and a node app. I connect them with HTTP services. now I put them on a local server with 192.168.x.y IP. I start my angular app by: 
`ng serve --port 8080 --host 192.168.x.y --public 151.233.t.z` which 151.233.t.z is my public IP. and finally, I run my apps by: `pm2 start npm -- start` and `pm2 start index.js`.**(my node server is listening on port 3000)** and in the HTTP services I send my HTTP request to `http://192.168.x.y:3000`. when I open the browser on 151.233.t.z:8080 on a local system everything is ok. but when I try outside the network I just can see my angular app and when I click on a button to send post request for login, it's not working!

Comment: Try use ngrok  it will host your 80 port outside network https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @ManojJadhav but I didn't use port 80! I don't understand what is the problem!! I think I cant access 192.168.x.y:3000 from 151.233.t.z:8080

Comment: Did you see any error in browser.? (check in Network tab)

Comment: Why do you expect it to work outside of your network. Your IP is not a public IP

Comment: @ManojJadhav yes when my angular app finished loading i see some `GET http://151.233.t.z/sockjs-node/info?t=1531295911743 0 ()` and '[WDS] Disconnected!'

Comment: @vibhor1997a whell i know it's not public! i don't know how to solve it and i wanna know is this the problem that doesnt let me login from another network?

Comment: For it to work publicly you need to do port forwarding and most probably its illegal then you can access the server on your public IP. Or just use a hosting service to host your server publicly.

Comment: @vibhor1997a well, I cannot use a hosting service! how should I do port forwarding? I opened port 3000 and 8080 on 192.168.x.y! what else should I do?

Comment: @ManojJadhav  can't you help me? I don't know what to do yet!!

Comment: @fariba.j I am not understand what your doing. but any way you can use ngrok with any port not only 80. Please try it.